# Refresh new data in RecyclerView on Android

Tags: android, json

I want develop android application for one website. I read website posts from `json` and show its in `RecyclerView` every 10 posts and when user scrolling on `RecyclerView` show more 10 post and go to end! in this project i use `okHTTP v3` and `RecyclerView`!
I want gonna put a button and when click on this button, load new data (if there was new data). 
**Button codes:**

```
    // Refresh Data
    toolbar_refresh.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            LoadData();
        }
    });
}
```

**Main Activity codes:**

```
public class Main_page extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final long RIPPLE_DURATION = 250;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private RelativeLayout root;
    private ImageView menu_image, toolbar_refresh;
    private RecyclerView main_recyclerView;
    private MainAdapter_loadMore mAdaper;
    private List<MainDataModel> dataModels = new ArrayList<MainDataModel>();
    protected Handler handler;
    private RelativeLayout loadLayout;
    private LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    private int pageCount = 1;
    String ServerAddress = ServerIP.getIP();
    private Context context;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_page);
        if (!EventBus.getDefault().isRegistered(this)) {
            EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
        }
        // Init
        handler = new Handler();
        context = getApplicationContext();
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.main_toolbar);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        loadLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_empty_layout);
        toolbar_refresh = (ImageView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_update);
        // Toolbar
        if (toolbar != null) {
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(null);
        }
        // Load First Data
        LoadData();
        // Menu
        root = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_root);
        View guillotineMenu = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.menu_layout, null);
        root.addView(guillotineMenu);
        menu_image = (ImageView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_logo);
        new GuillotineAnimation.GuillotineBuilder(guillotineMenu, guillotineMenu.findViewById(R.id.menu_layout_image), menu_image)
                .setStartDelay(RIPPLE_DURATION)
                .setActionBarViewForAnimation(toolbar)
                .setClosedOnStart(true)
                .build();
        // RecyclerView and setData
        main_recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.main_recycler);
        main_recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        main_recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mAdaper = new MainAdapter_loadMore(this, main_recyclerView, dataModels);
        main_recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdaper);
        // Load More data
        mAdaper.setOnLoadMoreListener(new OnLoadMoreListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadMore() {
                dataModels.add(null);
                mAdaper.notifyItemInserted(dataModels.size() - 1);
                LoadMoreData(pageCount);
            }
        });

        // Refresh Data
        toolbar_refresh.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                LoadData();
            }
        });
    }

    @Subscribe
    public void onEvent(List<MainDataModel> mainInfoModels) {
        if (dataModels.size() > 0) {
            dataModels.remove(dataModels.size() - 1);
            mAdaper.notifyItemRemoved(dataModels.size());
            mAdaper.setLoaded();
        }

        mAdaper.add(mainInfoModels);
        mAdaper.notifyDataSetChanged();
        pageCount++;

        if (dataModels.isEmpty()) {
            main_recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            loadLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        } else {
            main_recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            loadLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    private void LoadData() {
        MainDataInfo dataInfo = new MainDataInfo();
        // here getMainDataInfo() should return the server response
        dataInfo.getMainDataInfo(this);
    }

    private void LoadMoreData(int pageNumber) {
        MainDataInfo_loadMore dataInfo_loadMore = new MainDataInfo_loadMore();
        // here getMainDataInfo() should return the server response
        dataInfo_loadMore.getMainDataInfo_loadMore(this, pageNumber);
    }
}
```

**Adapter codes:**

```
public class MainAdapter_loadMore extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

    private List<MainDataModel> mDateSet;
    private Context mContext;

    private final int VIEW_ITEM = 1;
    private final int VIEW_PROG = 0;

    // The minimum amount of items to have below your current scroll position
    // before loading more.
    private int visibleThreshold = 5;
    private int lastVisibleItem, totalItemCount;
    private boolean loading;
    private OnLoadMoreListener onLoadMoreListener;

    public MainAdapter_loadMore(Context context, RecyclerView recyclerView, List<MainDataModel> dataSet) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mDateSet = dataSet;

        if (recyclerView.getLayoutManager() instanceof LinearLayoutManager) {

            final LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView
                    .getLayoutManager();
            recyclerView
                    .addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView,
                                               int dx, int dy) {
                            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                            totalItemCount = linearLayoutManager.getItemCount();
                            lastVisibleItem = linearLayoutManager
                                    .findLastVisibleItemPosition();
                            if (!loading
                                    && totalItemCount <= (lastVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
                                // End has been reached
                                // Do something
                                if (onLoadMoreListener != null) {
                                    onLoadMoreListener.onLoadMore();
                                }
                                loading = true;
                            }
                        }
                    });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return mDateSet.get(position) != null ? VIEW_ITEM : VIEW_PROG;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        RecyclerView.ViewHolder vh;
        if (viewType == VIEW_ITEM) {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.post_card_layout, parent, false);

            vh = new DataViewHolder(v);
        } else {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.progressbar_item, parent, false);

            vh = new ProgressViewHolder(v);
        }
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        if (holder instanceof DataViewHolder) {
            ((DataViewHolder) holder).main_post_title.setText(mDateSet.get(position).getTitle());
            Glide.with(mContext)
                    .load(mDateSet.get(position).getThumbnail())
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.post_image)
                    .crossFade()
                    .into(((DataViewHolder) holder).main_post_image);
            ((DataViewHolder) holder).main_post_content.setText(Html.fromHtml(mDateSet.get(position).getContent()));

        } else {
            ((ProgressViewHolder) holder).progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    public void setLoaded() {
        loading = false;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDateSet.size();
    }

    public void setOnLoadMoreListener(OnLoadMoreListener onLoadMoreListener) {
        this.onLoadMoreListener = onLoadMoreListener;
    }

    public void remove(int position) {
        mDateSet.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }

    public void clear() {
        mDateSet.clear();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    public void add(List<MainDataModel> models) {
        mDateSet.addAll(models);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void update(List<MainDataModel> models) {
        mDateSet.clear();
        mDateSet.addAll(models);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public class DataViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView main_post_title, main_post_content;
        private ImageView main_post_image;

        public DataViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            main_post_title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_content_title);
            main_post_image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_picture_image);
            main_post_content = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_content_text);
        }
    }

    public static class ProgressViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public AVLoadingIndicatorView progressBar;

        public ProgressViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            progressBar = (AVLoadingIndicatorView) v.findViewById(R.id.avloadingIndicatorView);
        }
    }
}
```

**AsyncTask code** (LoadData codes) :

```
public class MainDataInfo {
    private Context mContext;
    private String ServerAddress = ServerIP.getIP();

    public void getMainDataInfo(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        new getInfo().execute(ServerAddress + "page=1");
    }

    private class getInfo extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        EventBus bus = EventBus.getDefault();
        private String ou_response;
        private List<MainDataModel> infoModels;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            CustomProcessDialog.createAndShow(mContext);
            infoModels = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

            //String url = (String) params[0];
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(ServerAddress + "page=1")
                    .cacheControl(CacheControl.FORCE_NETWORK)
                    .build();

            Response response;
            try {
                response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                ou_response = response.body().string();
                response.body().close();
                if (ou_response != null) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject postObj = new JSONObject(ou_response);
                        JSONArray postsArray = postObj.optJSONArray("posts");
                        infoModels = new ArrayList<>();

                        for (int i = 0; i <= infoModels.size(); i++) {
                            JSONObject postObject = (JSONObject) postsArray.get(i);
                            JSONObject images = postObject.optJSONObject("thumbnail_images");
                            JSONObject imagesPair = images.optJSONObject("medium");

                            int id = postObject.getInt("id");
                            String title = postObject.getString("title");
                            String content = postObject.getString("content");
                            String thumbnail = imagesPair.getString("url");
                            Log.d("Data", "Post id: " + id);
                            Log.d("Data", "Post title: " + title);
                            Log.d("Data", "Post title: " + thumbnail);

                            //Use the title and id as per your requirement
                            infoModels.add(new MainDataModel(id, title, content, thumbnail));
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return ou_response;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            CustomProcessDialog.dissmis();
            if (result != null) {
                bus.post(infoModels);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When use this method `LoadData();` in button action, not load new data just copy fist 10 post and load again this first 10 post!
How can i fix it and when click on Button click action, load new data ?

**Attention :** Please don't give me negative points, help me and i really need you helps! thanks all <3

Comment: you again post this ?

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand your code but in your `AsyncTask` this method should like that :

```
public void getMainDataInfo(Context context,int page) {
    mContext = context;
    new getInfo().execute(ServerAddress + "page="+page);
}
```

**In your code you always getting page=1, there is no paging parameter in method**

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SwipeRefreshLayout` for this.